# Can't add JSON data source to refl.me

Tags: php, android, json, push-notification, messaging

I decided to try using refl.me app to create notifications via JSON. I created the JSON data source as in the [official documentation](https://refl.me/docs).

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$json_array =array('refl.me'=>true,'messages'=>'Hello!','refresh'=>96);
echo json_encode($json_array);
?>
```

Error. The app does not allow you to add a source. 
Why?

Comment: Found a mistake. "messages" instead of "message".

Comment: it is working properly with the change ? i found only that difference (message) in the working code of my implementation

Comment: Oh, no problem. Everything works.